# Transfer information to SD card (apps)

Tags: sd-card, lenovo

I have a problem transfering information to SD card on my Lenovo Vibe C. I had Lenovo A319 in the past and I bought Vibe C (Cause I broke the screen).It was much easier then and low time-consuming. I transfered the apps and other documents I needed from the old phone to the internal memory of my new one and then tried to put them on the SD card, but it takes too loong. Any ideas how to fix it?